# Laravel: Validate empty array in request

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application im trying to validate the body of my request, but one specific situation throws a ValidationException.

My code looks like this:

```
public function updateData(Request $request){
    try {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'ids' => ['required', 'array'],
            'ids.*' => 'integer'

        ]);
    catch (ValidationException $th) {
        return response()->json($this->createFailedResult($th->errors()));
    }
}
```

The Data I pass looks like this:

No Exception:

```
{
    ids: [1]
}
```

With Exception:

```
{
    ids: []
}
```

Thats the Ecception:

> [ids] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => The ids field is required.
>           )
>   )

I've read about exchanging "required" with "present", but i dont want empty strings to be ignored by the validation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tip: You can create specific requests to deal with validation, thereby having the controller just deal with the update-logic.

Comment: "Required" means that there MUST be a value there. `present` means that it will be required in the input, but can be empty. From the manual on "present", "*The field under validation must be present in the input data but can be empty.*"

Comment: You can also look into using the `sometimes` rule.

Answer (score 4):

> I've read about exchanging "required" with "present", but i dont want empty strings to be ignored by the validation.

The `present` validation rule requires the presence of the field.

A valid request with `present|array` contains one of the following:

```
{
    "ids": []
}
```

```
{
    "ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

If the validation rule was `required|array`, only the latter is valid.

By extending your validation rule with `'ids.*' => 'integer'`, you ensure that the provided input, if given any, is validated as integers. Therefore, the following would not be valid, even though the `ids` field is `present`:

```
{
    "ids": ["", "ipsum"]
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the 'ids.*' => 'integer' rule is ignored, if i put in the "present". Is there a way to combine these to rule, to have a propert validation?

Comment: What do you mean "ignored"? Are you saying you can add strings instead of integers and the validation fails?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. When I leave the "'ids.*' => 'integer'" Validation, I can pass An array of strings, and the validation does not fail

Comment: @Febertson That sounds really odd. Could you try and remove the try/catch? It's a weird construction and not something that is encouraged.